# How to get the buildtype in a build.gradle EARLY ON

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a React Native application and I'm trying to specify the folder for storing the generated source map in `project.ext.react` like so (I need it to implement a library which will help me debug JS errors)

```
project.ext.react = [
        ...
        extraPackagerArgs    : [ "--sourcemap-output", "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/$buildType/index.android.bundle.map" ]
]
```

As evident, the path should be something like `<buildDir>/intermediates/assets/<buildType>/index.android.bundle.map`

(e.g. 
`<buildDir>/intermediates/assets/release/index.android.bundle.map` in case of release and `<buildDir>/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle.map` in case of debug)

After referring to several answers on StackOverflow and outside, I'm getting the `buildType` in the build.gradle by declaring it first and then assigning it:

```
//3rd line of build.gradle
def buildType
....
//much later
   applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    buildType = variant.buildType.name 
....
```

However, this leads to a problem where `buildType` is initialized much after it is used, and so the output path becomes something like `<buildDir>/intermediates/assets/null/index.android.bundle.map`, thereby failing the whole process for me. Is there a way to get the build type earlier on?

Comment: Try to use `variant.name` instead of `buildType`

Comment: can I use that even without declaring a buildType variable?

Comment: `variant.name` did not work for my purpose

Comment: Library does not provide guide how to integrate it ?

Comment: The library hardcoded the buildType as "release" and so I'm having build failure in debug. Ideally I would like to see the library function correctly for one complete time before releasing it. (https://github.com/reyalpsirc/react-native-fabric-crashlytics)

Comment: And if you change that hardcoded part to develop? Do you need this library to work for all build variants?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183494/discussion-between-divyansh-goenka-and-parohy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found a way (though its not a very clean one) to look through the array of gradle tasks:

```
def buildType = gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any{it.toLowerCase().contains("debug")}?"debug":"release"
```

Answer (score 1):

We have under the `buildTypes` configuration inside `app.gradle` something like this:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        //def newApkName = "${APP_NAME}-${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
        def newApkName = "${APP_NAME}-${variant.name}-r${COMMIT_SHA}-${BRANCH_NAME}-v${variant.versionName}-${BUILD_NUMBER}.apk"

        variableFile.withWriterAppend { out ->
            out.writeLine("${APP_NAME}-${variant.name}=${APP_NAME}-${variant.name}-r${COMMIT_SHA}-${BRANCH_NAME}-v${variant.versionName}-${BUILD_NUMBER}")
            out.writeLine("${APP_NAME}-${variant.name}versionCode=${VERSION_CODE}")
            out.writeLine("${APP_NAME}-${variant.name}versionName=${variant.versionName}")
        }

        output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newApkName)
    }
}
```

This sets the apk name and the output folder for each `buildType` defined in gradle. We have buildTypes:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField('String', 'BUILD_ENV', '"Development"')
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    qa {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        buildConfigField('String', 'BUILD_ENV', '"QA"')
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        buildConfigField('String', 'BUILD_ENV', '"Production"')
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm already doing this, but the problem is this block is called after the react part has run. Is it possible to get the build type (since we always fire it knowingly) when the react part is running?

Comment: I need it in the Gradle script. I have a React Native project, and the React Native Packager runs some scripts before the Android Build takes over. So I need to know the build type at that time.