# App version depending on buildType - how to?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have done autoincrement build number and file name generation depending on buildType in my app. If buildType is "release" then appname will be like "app-v.1.0.0.apk" else if buildType is "debug" then appname will be like "app-v.1.0.0-debug+build.179.apk". It's working well, but values  not depending on buildType in the version.properties are always like "1.0.0-debug+build.179". How can I fix it? I think that my problem is in the scope, I can't override variable in variant, but I don't know how I can fix it. I have been trying fix my problem for a long time.

**version.properties:**

```
VERSION_NUMBER=1.0.0-debug+build.179
VERSION_MINOR=0
VERSION_BUILD=179
VERSION_PATCH=0
VERSION_MAJOR=1
```

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')

    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        Properties versionProps = new Properties()
        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

        def versionMajor = 1
        def versionMinor = 0
        def versionPatch = 0
        def versionBuild = versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger() + 1
        def versionNumber = "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}-debug+build.${versionBuild}"

        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                if (buildType.name == "release") {
                    versionNumber = versionNumber.split("-", 0)[0]
                }
                outputFileName = "app"
                outputFileName += "-v" + versionNumber + ".apk"
            }
        }

        versionProps['VERSION_MAJOR'] = versionMajor.toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_MINOR'] = versionMinor.toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'] = versionPatch.toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = versionBuild.toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'] = versionNumber.toString()

        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.my.app"
            minSdkVersion 28
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode versionBuild
            versionName "${versionNumber}"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    } else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me  what is expectation of debug apk name?

Comment: @Swayangjit debug and release apk name is correct, version apk isn't correct for release. It is "v.1.0.0-debug+build.179" for both version app. i expect that debug version app will be "v.1.0.0-debug+build.179" and release version app will be "v.1.0.0".

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I have found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53261807/7571239). BuildType can be define as

````
def buildType = gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any{it.toLowerCase().contains("debug")} ?
                        "debug" : "release"```
````

**build.gradle:**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

        def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')

        if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
            Properties versionProps = new Properties()
            versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

            def versionMajor = 1
            def versionMinor = 0
            def versionPatch = 0
            def versionBuild = versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger() + 1
            def versionNumber = "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}-" +
                                "debug+build.${versionBuild}"

            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    if (buildType.name == "release") {
                        versionNumber = versionNumber.split("-", 0)[0]
                    }
                    outputFileName = "app"
                    outputFileName += "-v" + versionNumber + ".apk"
                }
            }

            def buildType = gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any{it.toLowerCase().contains("debug")} ?
                            "debug" : "release"

            versionProps['VERSION_MAJOR'] = versionMajor.toString()
            versionProps['VERSION_MINOR'] = versionMinor.toString()
            versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'] = versionPatch.toString()
            versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = versionBuild.toString()

            if (buildType == "release"){
                versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'] = versionNumber.split("-", 0)[0]
            } else if (buildType == "debug"){
                versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'] = versionNumber.toString()
            }

            versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.my.app"
                minSdkVersion 28
                targetSdkVersion 29
                versionCode versionBuild
                versionName versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'].toString()
                testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not read version.properties!")
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            debug {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.3.0'
        implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    }
```